# Regular Expression to work on different locales

Tags: java, regex

I am using `ipconfig/all` command and regular expression in java to find out the MAC address.

I am searching `Physical Address` in the output of `ipconfig/all` command.

But problem is I want regular expression to work on different locale i.e. it can find the Physical Address for any locale.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could try checking for the MAC address itself - IIRC Windows shows it in the format `01-23-45-67-89-ab`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than searching for "Physical Address," or any other localized version of that (which will require you to add a localized version each time you need to support a new language), you could write just one regex to find the MAC address itself.

Since we know that a typical MAC addresses is comprised of six groupings of two hex digits each, separated by colons, periods, or dashes, the following regex will do it:

```
([a-fA-F0-9]{2}[:\-\.]){5}[a-fA-F0-9]{2}
```

Explanation:
(two hex digits followed by a colon :, repeated 5 times) (the final two hex digits)

Comment: minor correction: Windows partially uses its own convention, so you'd need to substitue the colon with a dash `-` (alas, not everywhere - sometimes `-` is used, sometimes `:`, sometimes nothing; this particular use has the dash)

Comment: Ah, good point. I've updated the regex to allow colons, dots, or dashes. Add as many special characters as you need. In some cases, I suppose there would be NO delimiter. If you're dealing with cases like that, you can also make the delimiter optional via `?` in regex.

Answer (score 1):

**OPTION 1:**

You can use a regexp like this (ENGLISH, FRENCH, SPANISH) :

```
/(Physical Address|Adresse Physique|Direccion fisica)/
```

Later check which locale you are using and update your regular expression consequently.

**OPTION 2:**

Use Java (JDK 1.6) directly to get the MAC adress

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.NetworkInterface;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MacAddress {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        //InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.0.158");

        /*
         * Get NetworkInterface for the current host and then read the
         * hardware address.
         */
        NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);
        if (ni != null) {
            byte[] mac = ni.getHardwareAddress();
            if (mac != null) {
                /*
                 * Extract each array of mac address and convert it to hexa with the
                 * following format 08-00-27-DC-4A-9E.
                 */
                for (int i = 0; i < mac.length; i++) {
                    System.out.format("%02X%s", mac[i], (i < mac.length - 1) ? "-" : "");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Address doesn't exist or is not accessible.");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Network Interface for the specified address is not found.");
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: 1) this will break on languages not in the list (XP at least supports some 30 language versions), 2) and as this is `ipconfig`, not `iptables` - Windows' source will not be readily available, meaning you need to get all the installations in various languages and get the description thence. 3) Woe betide you if the description changes in a new version of Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I get when I run `ipconfig /all`:

```
Adaptér sítě Ethernet Připojení k místní síti:
        Přípona DNS podle připojení . . . : example.com
        Popis . . . . . . . . . . . . . . : AMD PCNET Family PCI Ethernet Adapter
        Fyzická Adresa. . . . . . . . . . : DE-AD-BE-EF-CA-FE
        Protokol DHCP povolen . . . . . . : Ano
        Automatická konfigurace povolena  : Ano
        Adresa IP . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.158
        Maska podsítě . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Výchozí brána . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        Server DHCP . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        Servery DNS . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        Primární server WINS. . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        Zapůjčeno . . . . . . . . . . . . : 9. září 2011 16:05:32
        Zápůjčka vyprší . . . . . . . . . : 9. září 2011 20:05:32
```

As you can see, it is somewhat futile to look for the string "Physical Address", as there isn't one. However, note that Windows has its own format for MAC addresses - separating every two hex digits with a hyphen (and the alphabetical parts uppercase). So, looking for the regex:

```
([0-9A-F]{2}-){5}[0-9A-F]{2}
```

will give you the MAC address you're looking for.

Caveat: many computers have more than one network interface (wired and wifi, various VPNs, etc.), so there may be multiple MACs found in the output.

Comment: saakra toto je anglicke Forum :-) - this is English Forum, btw +1

Comment: @mKorbel: I'm kind of aware of that. As you may have noticed from paragraph #2, I'm using the localized texts to show that the string `Physical address` may not exist in the output, and [making a list of all possible l10ns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7362763/regular-expression-to-work-on-different-locales/7362823#7362823) is somewhat useless - which is why I propose looking directly for the MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

notice fo some computers especially for HP/Compaq MAC address should be accesible from

```
Process pcs = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic bios");
```

if is BIOS customized (Largiest Company) then this data should be accesible by using JNI/JNA (lots of VB/C# scripts around)

example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MAC_TEST {

    private static Pattern macPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:]"
            + "[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0 -9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}");

    private static List getWindowsMACAddresses() {
        try {
            //Process conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic bios");//for HP computers
            Process conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig /all");
            //Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("wmic bios /all");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conf.getInputStream()));
            return getMACAddresses(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Reading Windows MAC Address.");
        }
        return new ArrayList(1);
    }

    private static List getLinuxMACAddresses() {
        try {
            Process conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/sbin/ifconfig");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conf.getInputStream()));
            return getMACAddresses(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Reading Linux MAC Address.");
        }
        return new ArrayList(1);
    }

    private static List getHPUXMACAddresses() {
        try {
            Process conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/etc/lanscan");
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conf.getInputStream()));
            return getMACAddresses(input);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Reading HPUX MAC Address.");
        }
        return new ArrayList(1);
    }

    private static List getSolarisMACAddresses() {
        try {
            List rtc = new ArrayList(1);
            Process conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/sbin/arp "
                    + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(conf.getInputStream()));
            rtc.addAll(getMACAddresses(input));
            input.close();
            input = null;
            conf = null;
            //Solaris reports MAC address without first 0, change the pattern at re-test
            macPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F][-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}"
                    + "[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0 -9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}");
            conf = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/usr/sbin/arp "
                    + InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    conf.getInputStream()));
            rtc.addAll(getMACAddresses(input));
            //Revert pattern
            macPattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}"
                    + "[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0 -9a-fA-F]{2}[-:][0-9a-fA-F]{2}");
            return rtc;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error Reading Solaris MAC Address.");
        }
        return new ArrayList(1);
    }

    private static List getMACAddresses(BufferedReader input) throws Exception {
        List MACs = new ArrayList(1);
        String theLine;
        while ((theLine = input.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] ss = macPattern.split(theLine);
            for (int p = 0; p < ss.length; p++) {
                String s = theLine.substring(theLine.indexOf(ss[p]) + ss[p].length()).trim();
                if (!s.isEmpty()) {
                    String s1 = s.replaceAll("-", ":");
                    String s2 = s1.substring(0, s1.lastIndexOf(':') + 3);
                    if (s2.length() == 16 || s2.length() == 17) {
                        MACs.add(s2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return MACs;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println("WINDOWS ... Found the following MAC Addresses: ");
            List MACS = getWindowsMACAddresses();
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            for (int i = 0; i < MACS.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("|" + MACS.get(i) + "|");
            }
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Linux ...  Found the following MAC Addresses: ");
            MACS = getLinuxMACAddresses();
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            for (int i = 0; i < MACS.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("|" + MACS.get(i) + "|");
            }
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("Solaris ...  Found the following MAC Addresses: ");
            MACS = getSolarisMACAddresses();
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            for (int i = 0; i < MACS.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("|" + MACS.get(i) + "|");
            }
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println("HPUX ...  Found the following MAC Addresses: ");
            MACS = getHPUXMACAddresses();
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            for (int i = 0; i < MACS.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("|" + MACS.get(i) + "|");
            }
            System.out.println("*-----------------*");
            System.out.println(" ");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private MAC_TEST() {
    }
}
```